# delete multiple rows index out of bounds

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

I have a visualforce page with

```
<apex:commandButton value="Afficher" action="{!filterRecords}" reRender="table" immediate="true" />
```

in the constructor I have:

```
 public RCS(){
           counter = 0;
           rcsList = new list<T13_REPART_CS__c>(); 
           rcswrapperList = new list<rcswrapper>();
           for(Integer i=0;i<10;i++){
               rcswrapper rcsWrap = new rcswrapper(new T13_REPART_CS__c()); 
               counter++;
               rcsWrap.counterWrap = counter;
               rcswrapperList.add(rcsWrap); 

           }

    }
```

so I initially have 10 rows. When I click the button I want all rows to be deleted:

```
 public PageReference filterRecords(){

        Integer size = rcswrapperList.size();
        for(Integer i=0;i<size;i++){

             if(!rcswrapperList.isEmpty())
             {   rcswrapperList.remove(i);     
              }  
            }
          counter=0;
return null;
}
```

I get the following error:
System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to remove all items from a list is to call the list's [clear method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_clear).

Your code fails because the list is being made shorter as you go round the loop but the index you are passing to the `remove` method is growing. The quick fix would be to change `remove(i)` to `remove(0)` so you are always removing the first element of the list.

Comment: I answered the same thing. Deleting the answer now!